# What's the difference between const_iterator<T> and iterator<const T>?

Tags: c++, iterator, constants, const-iterator

Let's say I'm implementing a collection, say something like `std::vector`. I need to implement `iterator` and `const_iterator`, but once I've made `iterator` can `const_iterator` not just be implemented as `iterator<const T>` (where `T` is the type contained in the collection)?

There must be some reason why this doesn't work because there are a million questions about how to re-use code while implementing `iterator` and `const_iterator` but none of them say "just use `const T` as the type".

Answer (score 4):

`std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type` should be `T` for `const_iterator<T>`, but `const T`<sup>1</sup> for `iterator<const T>`. If you use `iterator<const T>` as `const_iterator<T>`, you would have to violate one of these assumptions.

It should possible to use a common template for both iterators as long as constness of the value type is a separate template argument from constness of the iterator. Something like:

```
template<class T>
struct container
{
    template<class ItPtr>
    struct iterator_common
    {
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = ItPtr;
        using reference = std::remove_pointer_t<ItPtr>&;
        // ...
    };

    using iterator = iterator_common<T*>;
    using const_iterator = iterator_common<const T*>;
    // ...
};
```

<sup>1</sup> Until C++20, in which it should be `std::remove_cv_t<const T>` which is `T`. As such, this won't be a problem to your suggestion in the future standard version.